# Why "kubectl describe job xxx" got TooManyActivePods?

Tags: kubernetes

I‘m running the job example https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: pi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

I got some warning

```
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulCreate        Created pod: pi-5n0vn
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulDelete        Deleted pod: pi-5n0vn
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulDelete        Deleted pod: pi-qlp5f
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulCreate        Created pod: pi-j9z6s
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulCreate        Created pod: pi-qlp5f
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulCreate        Created pod: pi-mf1j9
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulDelete        Deleted pod: pi-mf1j9
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulDelete        Deleted pod: pi-j9z6s
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulDelete        Deleted pod: pi-qlp5f
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulCreate        Created pod: pi-w3m2m
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulDelete        Deleted pod: pi-qlp5f
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulDelete        Deleted pod: pi-5n0vn
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulCreate        Created pod: pi-nww4h
  23m           23m             2       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulDelete        Deleted pod: pi-p8pt9
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Warning         FailedDelete            Error deleting: pods "pi-mf1j9" not found
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulDelete        Deleted pod: pi-w3m2m
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulCreate        Created pod: pi-69l9r
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulCreate        Created pod: pi-p8pt9
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulDelete        Deleted pod: pi-69l9r
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Normal          SuccessfulDelete        Deleted pod: pi-p8pt9
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Warning         TooManyActivePods       Too many active pods running after completion count reached
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Warning         TooManyActivePods       Too many active pods running after completion count reached
  23m           23m             1       {job-controller }                       Warning         TooManyActivePods       Too many active pods running after completion count reached
```

Why start so many pod and delete it?

I can't delete the job

```
[root@c3-sa-i2-20151229-buf023 ~]# kubectl delete job pi
error: timed out waiting for "pi" to be synced
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--grace-period=0 --force` to your delete command.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods

> The kubectl delete command supports the --grace-period= option which allows a user to override the default and specify their own value. The value 0 force deletes the pod. In kubectl version >= 1.5, you must specify an additional flag --force along with --grace-period=0 in order to perform force deletions.

Comment: Thanks for response, I know how to delete the job. I do not know why created so many pod, and delete it.

Comment: If you execute `kubectl describe job pi` that might give you a hint. By default a Job tries to run at least on Pod to *completion*, that is a zero exit status. I think all of these Pods failed to do that so the Job keeps trying. Why the Pod fails is another question. Not enough memory perhaps?